# Crontab @reboot command not attaching to a screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I run a minecraft server on a remotely hosted linux VPS. Recently, a migration was done at my host's data center where the VPS image was copied to a new setup (new hardware, new IP, new virtual infrastructure I believe).

Before the migration, the server had the below command crontab'd and it worked fine; after a full reboot, I could type "screen -x" to get into the server console. After the migration, I cannot do this anymore. The command itself starts the minecraft server... but not the 'screen'. I have asked the host to explore why and he tested it out and replied he can't find the reason either.

The main changes I know of at the time of migration...  upgrade from 13.x to 14.04 Ubuntu; update from Java 6 to Java 8...  update to newest MySQL...  storage upgraded to SSD. Changed from "Xen" to "KVM"... and new setup supported by OpenStack.

@reboot cd /home/mcma && screen -dmS minecraft /home/mcma/MCMA2_Linux_x86_64

I wish I could provide more info but this is everything I have at hand, I don't know how to troubleshoot further. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you could take a moment to give thoughts instead of silently downvoting, it would greatly help.

Comment: _'he can't find the reason'_ - are you paying for this? If so, this is not good enough. Your ISP should know what they've done.

Comment: These were his specific comments: "After quite a bit of testing I can't put a finger on it. It refuses to attach after being started with cron. Starting screen normally as the root user will let you reattach. The only suggestion I could make is switching to tmux or setting up another way to do what you're wanting."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas to try:

1. Check if the cron daemon is running.
2. If it does, check the logs to see if it attempts to start the given cron job. Might need to crank up the log level for this.
3. If the job does get launched, check the the error.
4. Try using absolute path to `screen`.
5. If `/home/mcma/MCMA2_Linux_x86_64` is a script, try adding `sh` before it.
6. Have you tried running the command by hand?
7. The Internets seem to imply there might be a bug with non-root `@reboot` jobs on some Ubuntus. Which cron daemon are you using?
8. Check Ubuntu bug [574773](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen/+bug/574773). It might be the issue you are having.

Let me know if you gather any additional data from above, so we can try a few more things as needed.